# What is the canonical way to see if an image exists in the docker public registry?

Tags: docker, dockerhub, docker-registry

We want to check if an image exists in the public registry (Docker Hub) automatically before we start a deployment. With the v1 API, we would just query `https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/gliderlabs/alpine/tags/3.2` for example.

But now the official API for the registry is v2, what is the official way of checking the existence of an image in the **public** registry?

**v1**

```
$ curl -i https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/gliderlabs/alpine/tags/latest
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Tue, 11 Aug 2015 10:02:09 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000

[{"pk": 20307475, "id": "5bd56d81"}, {"pk": 20355979, "id": "511136ea"}]
```

**v2**:

```
$ curl -i https://index.docker.io/v2/repositories/gliderlabs/alpine/tags/latest
HTTP/1.1 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Tue, 11 Aug 2015 10:04:20 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Location: https://index.docker.io/v2/repositories/gliderlabs/alpine/tags/latest/
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000

$ curl -i https://index.docker.io/v2/repositories/gliderlabs/alpine/tags/latest/
HTTP/1.1 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Tue, 11 Aug 2015 10:04:26 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Location: https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/gliderlabs/alpine/tags/latest/
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000

$ curl -i https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/gliderlabs/alpine/tags/latest/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Tue, 11 Aug 2015 10:04:34 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Allow: GET, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000

{"name": "latest", "full_size": 5250074, "id": 130839, "repository": 127805, "creator": 152141, "last_updater": 152141, "image_id": null, "v2": false}
```

Am I supposed to stick to the `v1` url even though it is now kind of deprecated or use `v2` URLs but there is no documentation about it? If I use `v2`, shall I use directly `https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/` or still use `https://index.docker.io/v1/` and follow the redirects?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30113726/docker-registry-2-0-api-v2

Comment: This is not a duplicate, the linked question is about the private registry that you can run yourself, this question is about the public registry i.e. dockerhub.

Comment: The v2 api is spec'd out at https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/docs/spec/api.md. That is a part of the distribution project which lets you run a private registry.

Comment: @Kasisnu Yes I know that but there is no official word for the public registry. Going to add a bit of details to the question.

Comment: @jtblin Did you ever rind a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Upstream's `download-frozen-image-v2.sh` script should be of some use as at least a decent API example here (https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/6bf8844f1179108b9fabd271a655bf9eaaf1ee8c/contrib/download-frozen-image-v2.sh#L47-L54).

The main key is that you'll need to be hitting `registry-1.docker.io` instead of `index.docker.io`, and that you need a "token" from `auth.docker.io` (https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:gliderlabs/alpine:pull), even if you're just requesting read-only access to a public repository.  Once you've got that token, you can hit `https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/gliderlabs/alpine/manifests/latest` with an `Authorization` header which will either return the JSON manifest of the image or error out with a 404.

```
token="$(curl -sSL "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:$image:pull" | jq --raw-output .token)"

curl -fsSL -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/$image/manifests/$digest"
```