# Public Docker v2 API Endpoints

Tags: api, docker

Would someone know the equivalent URIs that are in v1:

```
registry.hub.docker.com/v1/  
index.docker.io/v1/
```

of what they are now for the public Internet sites in v2?

I've checked docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/ for such URIs and on this site but everything keeps pointing back to a v1 address.

Goal here is in python to search for the public (not private) docker image then by it's search name pull the image down from the repository.

> > > again, there is not about discussion of the local registry APIs that have been discussed. <<<

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker registry 2.0 API v2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30113726/docker-registry-2-0-api-v2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just inspected the network request and found this. Maybe it'll help

```
https://hub.docker.com/v2/search/repositories/?query=alpine
```

So I think the answer to your question is just `hub.docker.com/v2`, but reading the [API v2 Roadmap](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/docs/spec/api.md#detail), it isn't too clear on what all the endpoints and their supported parameters are (the Docker Hub REST API seems to be undocumented, unlike the Docker Registry API).

Comment: @ cricket_007: yes, I tried it now at it works can server both of my prior URL needs. Thanks!