# Where does the docker images stored in local machine

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I created docker a docker image of a spring boot application using the below command

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t myimage
```

once i run the command "docker images" I see that image. Now I want to get that image out my local machine and run on another machine using the below command.

```
docker run -p 8085:8085 myimage
```

What are the steps to relocate docker image to another machine over a physical medium?

/var/lib/docker/images/overlay2/imagedb/content

but that local contain .txt files of 6KB. I know normally a docker image is around 600MB in size.

Could anyone please help me to find the exact location.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save all docker images and copy to another machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35575674/how-to-save-all-docker-images-and-copy-to-another-machine)

Comment: I'd never poke around by hand in `/var/lib/docker` for anything.  Good options include `docker push` the image to some registry, check out your source repository and `docker build` on the target machine, or `docker save`/`docker load`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to share my Docker-Image without using the Docker-Hub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482822/how-to-share-my-docker-image-without-using-the-docker-hub)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1.You can export your docker image after building it.

`docker build -f Dockerfile -t myimage .`

`docker save myimage > myimage.tar` You will see this in your directory where you execute docker build command.

Then you can load it anywhere else as

`docker load < myimage.tar`

Other than that if there is a docker repo , you can simply push the docker image.

Reference:- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/#options

2.If the `other machine` can be reachable via a network you can setup the other machine as a docker hub