# Converting docker tar file into a singularity image?

Tags: docker, singularity-container

I am new to both Docker and Singularity.  I recently created the canonical `main.c`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    printf("Hello Docker World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I statically compiled this code, i.e.

```
gcc -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -o hello main.c
```

I then built the docker image and could run it, i.e.

```
dockerd &  ## Start Docker daemon
docker build --tag hello .
docker run hello   ## Outputs "Hello Docker World"
```

I then [save](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24485196/4021436) the image so that I can export it to a second computer (which does not have docker, but does have singularity), i.e.

```
docker save hello > hello.tar
```

Now on the second machine, which does not have docker but does have singularity, I want to create a singularity image.  Tthe singularity [documentation](https://singularity.lbl.gov/docs-docker) give instructions on creating a singularity image from a docker image on Docker Hub, but they do not give instructions on converting from a docker tar'd file.

Question : How would I create a singularity image from my `hello.tar`

Comment: why not publish it to dockerhub and use ?

Comment: I have code I don't want to make public.

Comment: Then create a local docker registery and push the image to local registery. Use that for singularity.

Comment: The second machine is CentOS 6.9.  It does not seem that it is supported by Docker (https://success.docker.com/article/compatibility-matrix).  I'd previously tried to install docker on this machine, but was unable to get a working version.

Comment: IN this case, you should use singularity export on your first machine and import on another.

Answer (score 8):

1. First, save your docker image.

   `sudo docker save image_id -o local.tar`
2. Then copy to another machine in any way you like
3. Finally, build a singularity image from the `local.tar` by

   `singularity build local_tar.sif docker-archive://local.tar`

   which used the docker-archive bootstrap agent. Can read it [here](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.1/user-guide/singularity_and_docker.html)

Comment: How can I do this if I don't have access to docker on the machine in step 3?

Comment: I get `ERROR: Unknown container build Singularity recipe format: docker-archive://local.tar
ABORT: Aborting with RETVAL=255`

Comment: @RuolinLiu I tried the same method to do the conversion which as you mentioned is on the official singularity website as well. But the problem I face is that the converted image is quite small as compared to the original image (approx 1/3rd) which makes me believe that the build is skipping all the packages (perhaps custom ones) in the original docker image. Do you have any ideas as to what's going on here?

Comment: Try this. `singularity build local_tar.sif local.tar` It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Ruolin Liu is what I would recommend trying first.

Another thing you could try is the tool [docker2singularity](https://github.com/singularityhub/docker2singularity/).
docker2singularity is itself a docker image so it is easy to install.
Furthermore it offers support for current and older versions of singularity.

As an [example](https://github.com/singularityhub/docker2singularity/#examples) of how to use docker2singularity on your `hello` docker image you would...

1. make a directory to write the singularity image file to

   ```
   mkdir -p /tmp/test
   ```
2. use docker2singularity on the docker image `hello` and mount `/tmp/test` as the output directory

   ```
   docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
   -v /tmp/test:/output \
   --privileged -t --rm \
   quay.io/singularity/docker2singularity \
   hello
   ```
3. move the created singularity image file from `/tmp/test` to a host with singularity and run it

Answer (score 0):

Use local registry container as below:

```
# Start a docker registry
$ docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
# Push local docker container to it
$ docker tag alpine localhost:5000/alpine
$ docker push localhost:5000/alpine
# Create def file for singularity like this..
# (add your modifications)
Bootstrap: docker
Registry: http://localhost:5000
Namespace:
From: alpine:latest
# Build singularity container
$ sudo SINGULARITY_NOHTTPS=1 singularity build alpine.simg def
```